# What's the interpretation of `type` for a std::vector instead of a cv::Mat in OpenCV and how can I change it? (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, mat

I want to use the `adaptiveThreshold` function from *OpenCV* which is defined in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html) as follows:

```
void adaptiveThreshold(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, double maxValue, int adaptiveMethod, int thresholdType, int blockSize, double C)
```

Instead of using a `Mat` as an input, I want to use a `vector<double>`. This should be possible, as I read the following in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#inputarray):

> When you see in the reference manual or in *OpenCV* source code a
>   function that takes `InputArray`, it means that you can actually pass
>   `Mat`, `Matx`, `vector<T>` etc. (see above the complete list).

I am using the following code:

```
vector<double> diffs; // <initialized with a number of double values>
double maxValue = 255.0; // values in diffs above the threshold will be set to 255.0
vector<double> out; // stores the output values (either 0 or 255.0)
adaptiveThreshold(diffs, out, maxValue, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 3, 0);
```

However, when running the code I get the following error:

> **OpenCV Error**: Assertion failed (`src.type() == CV_8UC1`) in
>   `adaptiveThreshold`, file
>   */Users/nburk/Developer/SDKs/opencv-2.4.10/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp*,
>   *line 796*
>
> `libc++abi.dylib`: **terminating with uncaught exception of type**
>   `cv::Exception`:
>   */Users/nburk/Developer/SDKs/opencv-2.4.10/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp:796*:
>   **error: (-215)** `src.type() == CV_8UC1` in function `adaptiveThreshold`

Now, I understand the call fails because the `type` of the input is not actually `CV_8UC1`. But I don't know how to solve this issue. I thought the `type` property is only relevant to `Mat` objects, I don't know how to interpret it for `vector`.

I also am not sure where to read about this issue in the docs. I found the following statement in the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat) for `Mat`, but this doesn't help me a lot to solve my issue:

> **type** – Array type. Use `CV_8UC1`, ..., `CV_64FC4` to create 1-4 channel
>   matrices, or `CV_8UC(n)`, ..., `CV_64FC(n)` to create multi-channel (up to
>   `CV_CN_MAX` channels) matrices.

**Update**: The above says that `type` actually is an *Array type*, but what does this mean? How can I make it so that my `vector<double>` gets the type `CV_8UC1` that is required to use `adaptiveThreshold`?

**Another update**:
After reading in the *Learning OpenCV* book from *O'Reilly*, I learned the following:

> `type` can be any of a long list of predefined types of the form:
>   `CV_<bit_depth>(S|U|F) C<number_of_channels>`. Thus, the matrix could
>   consist of *32-bit floats* (`CV_32FC1`), of *un-signed integer 8-bit
>   triplets* (`CV_8UC3`), or of countless other elements.

So, it's obvious that in my case the `vector<double>` is not of type `CV_8UC1` because `double` is clearly not an `_unsigned 8-bit integer`. However, I can just normalize these values which I just did. The result is a `vector<int>` that only has values between `0` and `255`. Thus, it should be of type `CV_8UC1`, right? However, I am still getting the same error...

Comment: Types do not match. INT and UNSIGNED CHAR are different. Try to cast vector<int> to vector<unsigned char> and then it should work.

Comment: thanks! that fixes the issue indeed! however, I am getting another assertion error now (`mtype == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(mtype) == CV_MAT_CN(type0) && ((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0)`) ... anyway, this problem is solved thanks to your hint. if you post your comment as an answer, I'm going to accept it. :)

Comment: Are you getting this error in the same function ?

Comment: no, it says it occurs in _in create, file /Users/nburk/Developer/SDKs/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1486_

Comment: Are you trying to get output vector as a type of double?

Comment: yes indeed, is that the problem? I thought it would make sense because `maxValue` has to be a double, so I'd expect the output to be set as `double` as well.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html read here. Src and dst should be same size and type.

Comment: wow, I overread that! thanks so much for your help, the errors are completely gone now!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types do not match. `int` and `unsigned char` are different. Try to cast `vector<int>` to `vector<unsigned char>` and then it should work.